# how to send html email in default mail client for mac and pc?

Tags: html, email, sendmail

Im trying to set up a website where i can send an email of the webpage the client is looking at. They will click on a button and it open up their default mail client (whether it be on mac and PC) which will populate the email subject and body. Maybe a oft file but doesn't look like its compatible with mac outlook

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank You

P.s. i needed the body to include a hyperlinked JPEG

Comment: You can't send html via mailto: so how to you envisage your idea working?

Comment: Don't think it's possible to access the way the client is looking at the webpage. What is "a oft file"?

Answer (score 0):

use `<a href="mailto:email@website.com?subject=Subject&body=Body">E-Mail Us</a>` to populate subject and body text which then opens in a users default mail client

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention, i needed the body to include a hyperlinked JPEG. thank you for your reply though

Comment: No need for this to be downvoted, it answered the original question before the edits.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="mailto:support@mydomain.net?subject=SUBJECT&body=BODY HERE">Link to do that</a>
```

to get the page you would have to use php or hard code the url as html doesn't have the option.

Comment: You are missing the `href` attribute

Comment: @Andy Oops my bad, I have fixed this now.